# why timestamps col is null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I added timestamps cols into DB table,

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('allestates', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and also give true into table's model.

```
    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $table = "allestates";
```

But still when I add new data timestamps cols are Null? Any idea why it like this? 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timestamps is null because maybe you don't use laravel eloquent when you insert data.

```
$model= new model;

$model->column_one= 'John';

$model->save();
```

Or You can use,

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('allestates', function (Blueprint $table) {
             $table->created_at = $table->freshTimestamp();
        });
    }
```

//model

```
 public $timestamps = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your timestamp doesn't make use of eloquent it wont work so you might have to manually set the timestamps on your insert statement

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
         DB::table('user_languages')->updateOrInsert([
             'id' => //user_id goes here
             'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
             'updated_at' => Carbon::now()
         ]);
```